# Swift 4 handling nil values from Firestore with CodableFirebase and custom classes

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, swift4, codable

I'm using the library [CodableFirebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) to decode and encode data when working with Google's Firestore. It works great, except if a value is not defined in the database but is a property of the class. I am wondering how do you define the class so that when the snapshot comes back from Firebase it doesn't puke on the nil value.

Here's a simple example of what is happening.. This would be my class definition.

```
class TimeThing: Codable {
 var requestedTime: Double?
 var createdTime: Double?

 init(
    requestedTime: Double? = 0,
    createdTime: Double? = 0
    ) {
     self.requestedTime = requestedTime
     self.createdTime = createdTime
}}
```

And this would be the error that's getting thrown. createdTime, in this case, has a value in Firestore where 'requestedTime' doesn't.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Double, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "requestedTime", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Double but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))

I realize I'm missing something fundamental, but unfortunately I'm just not sure what that is. What do I need to do to my class to set defaults that will not blow up my try block when experiencing a nil value from Firestore?

Thanks!!

Comment: post the json .......

Comment: Google's Firestore doesn't return JSON, but returns Snapshots, which is essentially a dictionary of the object requested. CodableFirebase converts that into objects that can be directly referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the core of the issue was that the defaults in the class were incorrectly defined.

```
class TimeThing: Codable {
 var requestedTime: Double?
 var createdTime: Double?

 init(
    requestedTime: Double? = 0,
    createdTime: Double? = 0
    ) {
     self.requestedTime = requestedTime
     self.createdTime = createdTime
}}
```

should have been

```
class TimeThing: Codable {
 var requestedTime: Double? = 0
 var createdTime: Double? = 0

 init(
    requestedTime: Double,
    createdTime: Double
    ) {
     self.requestedTime = requestedTime
     self.createdTime = createdTime
}}
```

Once I fixed that, the defaults were there for **CodableFirebase** to decode.